# I want to get each month expense from three table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mysqli

I have three table named `"salary"`, `"allowance"` and `"bill"`.

`"salary"` table has

```
 s_id [primary key], E_ID, S_Amount, S_Date.
```

`"allowanace"` table has

```
 A_ID[primary key], E_ID, A_TA, A_DA, A_MA, A_Others, A_Date, Total_A
```

`"bill"` table has

```
 E_ID[primary key], Electric, Gas, Water, B_Others, B_Date Total_B
```

I have joined these tables with this query>>

```
 SELECT 
     SUM(allowance.`A_TA`+allowance.`A_DA`
     +allowance.`A_MA`+allowance.`A_Others`)
     AS Total_Allowance, 
     (SUM(salary.`S_Amount`)) AS Total_Salary, 
      SUM(bill.`Electric`+bill.`Water`+bill.`Gas`+bill.`B_Others`) as 
      Total_Bill,
     (SUM(allowance.`A_TA`+allowance.`A_DA`+allowance.`A_MA`
      +allowance.`A_Others`)+SUM(salary.`S_Amount`)
      +SUM(bill.`Electric`+bill.`Water`+bill.`Gas`+bill.`B_Others`))
      AS Total_Ex 
      from salary
      INNER JOIN allowance
      ON salary.E_ID=allowance.E_ID 
      INNER JOIN bill
      ON salary.S_Date=bill.B_Date
```

I want to get the total expense "Total_Ex" of january 2015, December 2015, October 2016, november 2016...each month's total expense separately.

Comment: I used >>>> WHERE YEAR(A_Date)= $op1 AND YEAR(S_Date)= $op1 AND YEAR(B_Date)= $op1
  AND MONTH(A_Date)=1 AND MONTH(S_Date)=1 AND MONTH(B_Date)=1
  GROUP BY  YEAR(A_Date)=$op1,YEAR(S_Date)=$op1,YEAR(B_Date)=$op1, MONTH(A_Date=1),MONTH(S_Date=1), MONTH(B_Date=1);")  <<<to solve this. but it only works when a month has only one employee's total. If a month has two or more employee's total, it doesn't work.

Comment: Edit your question don't add more info in the comment section. Some info on how to ask a question in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SUM and IF:

```
SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(salary.S_Date,'%M')='January',
allowance.A_TA+allowance.A_DA+allowance.A_MA
+allowance.A_Others
+salary.S_Amount+bill.Electric+bill.Water
+bill.Gas+bill.B_Others,0)) AS 
Jan_Total_Ex
```

This will give you Jan total expense.

Comment: Thank you. How can i select year? If i want to select january 2015, what will be query?

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(salary.S_date,'%M %Y').` You can check [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/) for further customization.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?
SELECT convert(varchar(8), bill.B_Date,120) +'01', SUM(allowance.A_TA+allowance.A_DA+allowance.A_MA+allowance.A_Others) AS Total_Allowance, 
(SUM(salary.S_Amount)) AS Total_Salary, SUM(bill.Electric+bill.Water+bill.Gas+bill.B_Others) as Total_Bill, 
(SUM(allowance.A_TA+allowance.A_DA+allowance.A_MA+allowance.A_Others)+SUM(salary.S_Amount)+SUM(bill.Electric+bill.Water+bill.Gas+bill.B_Others))
    AS Total_Ex 
    from salary
          INNER JOIN allowance
          ON salary.E_ID=allowance.E_ID 
          INNER JOIN bill
          ON salary.S_Date=bill.B_Date
          group by convert(varchar(8), bill.B_Date,120) +'01'

Comment: Can you please give a little description. I am new at this. Some description would be very helpful. Thanks.